# Consistency of bibliography incollection vs article

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I am using bibtex with imported bibliography, however I was asked to make it consistent.

```
@article {MR2735939,
    AUTHOR = {Zhang, Liping and Wu, Soon-Yi and L\'{o}pez, Marco A.},
     TITLE = {A new exchange method for convex semi-infinite programming},
   JOURNAL = {SIAM J. Optim.},
  FJOURNAL = {SIAM Journal on Optimization},
    VOLUME = {20},
      YEAR = {2010},
    NUMBER = {6},
     PAGES = {2959--2977},
      ISSN = {1052-6234},
   MRCLASS = {90C34 (65K05 90C30)},
  MRNUMBER = {2735939},
MRREVIEWER = {Francisco Guerra-V\'{a}zquez},
       DOI = {10.1137/090767133},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1137/090767133},
}
@incollection {MR2175672,
    AUTHOR = {Guerra V\'{a}zquez, Francisco and R\"{u}ckmann, Jan-J.},
     TITLE = {Semi-infinite programming: properties and applications to
              economics},
    BOOKTITLE = {New tools of economic dynamics},
    SERIES = {Lecture Notes in Econom. and Math. Systems},
    VOLUME = {551},
     PAGES = {373--393},
 PUBLISHER = {Springer, Berlin},
      YEAR = {2005},
   MRCLASS = {91B02 (90C34 91-02)},
  MRNUMBER = {2175672},
       DOI = {10.1007/3-540-28444-3_22},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-28444-3_22},
}
```

The output is as such:

```
Liping Zhang, Soon-Yi Wu, and Marco A. López. A new exchange method for convexsemi-infinite programming.SIAM J. Optim., 20(6):2959–2977, 2010.

Francisco Guerra Vázquez and Jan-J. Rückmann. Semi-infinite programming: propertiesand applications to economics. InNew tools of economic dynamics, volume 551 ofLectureNotes in Econom. and Math. Systems, pages 373–393. Springer, Berlin, 2005.
```

In particular I would like to know how to change volumes so that they are consistent. Instead of "volume 551 ofLectureNotes in Econom" I would like 551:373-393. I could just change incollection to article, but is this valid?

Comment: You should only ever use the `@article` entry type for pieces published in scholarly journals. No exceptions.

Comment: Please do tell us which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: @Mico as in the first article.

Comment: "as in the first article" -- sorry, I don't understand this reference. Where in the "rfirst article" is a `\bibliographystyle` directive?

Comment: In this case your `volume` of your `incollection` should probably be `number`, which (at least in `biblatex`) refers to the volume or number in the series. (If you're not using `biblatex`, this might not print anything of course.)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "volume" in (a) a scholarly journal and (b) a series of books is completely different. No useful purpose is served by trying to establish a "consistent look" across items which have nothing in common except the field name, `volumr`.

Entries of type `@article` should only ever be used for pieces published in scholarly journals. No exceptions to this rule.

Rather than try to establish a "consistent look" where none is called for, I would concentrate on providing information that's actually useful for readers. In the case of the entry with key `MR2175672`, I would provide information for the `editor`and `chapter` fields, and I would split the information currently contained in the `publisher` field into separate `publisher` and `address` fields.

With these adjustments in place, you rnn safely dispense with the `series` and `volume` fields, thereby "solving" the "consistent look" issue as well.

```
@incollection{MR2175672,
  author       = "Guerra V{\'a}zquez, Francisco and R{\"u}ckmann, Jan-J.",
  title        = "Semi-infinite programming: Properties and applications to economics",
  booktitle    = "New Tools of Economic Dynamics",
  editor       = "Jacek Leskow and Mart{\'i}n Puchet and Lionello F. Punzo",
  xseries       = "Lecture Notes in Economics and Mathematical Systems",
  xvolume       = 551,
  pages        = "373--393",
  chapter      = 22,
  publisher    = "Springer",
  address      = "Berlin",
  year         = 2005,
  mrclass      = "91B02 (90C34 91-02)",
  mrnumber     = 2175672,
  doi          = "10.1007/3-540-28444-3_22",
  url          = "https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-28444-3_22",
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question as for now I know what styles are, should I combine styles article, incollection and books in one work? For instance there is a problem that in incollection it states pages 373-393 and in article it is just 373-393.

Comment: @ryszardeggink - I wouldn't worry about this "inconsistency" either: In the case of entries of type `@article`, it's not necessary to prefix the string `pages` as the rante of numbers can only refer to page ranges. In contrast, for entries of type `@book` and `@incollection`, it's generally helpful to provide this string to help distinguish the meaning of the numbers from other potential candidates, such as chapter and volume numbers. At any rate, if you can't stand how the bibliography style formats entries, you may see fit to employ another one.